# Getting Data Inside noscript Tag In Python Using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am attempting trying to retrieve some data inside a noscript tag. I can get all the data from the tag but I cant seem to figure out how to parse it further.

HTML

```
<noscript>
    <img src="https://us.louisvuitton.com/images/is/image/lv/1/PP_VP_L/louis-vuitton-key-pouch-monogram-key-holders-and-bag-charms--M62650_PM2_Front%20view.jpg" alt="Monogram Accessories Key Holders and Bag Charms Key Pouch | Louis Vuitton ®">
  </noscript>
```

Code:

```
req = requests.get(self.url, headers= self.HEADERS)
page_soup = soup(req.text, "html5lib")

img_url = page_soup.find("noscript")
print(img_url)
```

Output:

```
<noscript><img alt="Monogram Accessories Key Holders and Bag Charms Key Pouch | Louis Vuitton ®" src="https://us.louisvuitton.com/images/is/image/lv/1/PP_VP_L/louis-vuitton-key-pouch-monogram-key-holders-and-bag-charms--M62650_PM2_Front%20view.jpg"/></noscript>
```

Wanted Output:

```
"https://us.louisvuitton.com/images/is/image/lv/1/PP_VP_L/louis-vuitton-key-pouch-monogram-key-holders-and-bag-charms--M62650_PM2_Front%20view.jpg"
```

Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find the `img` tag inside the `noscript` tag, then get the `src` attribute.

```
noscript = page_soup.find("noscript")
if noscript:
    img = noscript.find("img")
    if img:
        img_url = img['src']
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it has got me closer to my solution.  Unfortunately,  `img_url` returns as **None** .

Comment: Sorry, it should be `img['src']`